# Is there a way to delete an already activated AppBundle from Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I tried updating the app. However, it was rejected by Google. The reason was that the “REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES” permission was used. Surprisingly, the version I tried to update doesn't use that permission.

I investigated where those permissions are being used. That permission was used in a version a year ago. When I looked through the app bundle explorer, the Release Status of the old version of the app was active. Even after updating the version, it strangely survived.

Is there any way to delete the app bundle whose Release Status is Active?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete an artifact that has been already released in a track. However you can publish another version on top of it with a higher versionCode to replace it.